# JSONifying a Blob file

Tags: javascript, json, blob, typedarray

I am trying to JSONify a blob file so that I can send it over AJAX requests. I have tried with the code below without any success. When I parse a JSONified file, I only get a different file with much smaller size.

```
function test(blob, cb) {

        var fileReader = new FileReader()
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
        fileReader.onloadend = function() {             

            // client
            var arry = Array.from(new Uint8Array(fileReader.result))
            var data = {data: arry }
            var json = JSON.stringify(data)

            // server
            var parse = JSON.parse(json)
            var arr = parse.data.buffer
            var blob = new Blob([arr])
       }        
}
```

Comment: The object you call JSON.stringify on (**data**) does not have property **buffer**, which is accessed in your **server** part.

Comment: @xxxmatko Thanks for pointing out my mistake. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I've just posted that as an answer, also with sample code, hope it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use FileReader.readAsDataURL() method, and send the data as base64 encoded string, and than decode it on the server side. Base64 string will be much smaller than json string representing an array.

Here is an example

```js
function getBase64() {
  var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
   document.getElementById("result").value = reader.result;
  }, false);
  
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="getBase64()" />
<br/>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Comment: I tried this exact same approach using a blob that I had created programmatically from a stream using the `MediaRecorder` API, and all I got was "data:". Is there something with data security that prevents this method from reading files that the user didn't explicitly submit using an input element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

JQuery example (for simplicity):

```
var oFormData = new FormData();
$(':input', this).each(function (){
    if(this.name){
        var oValue = this.value;
        if(this.type == 'file'){
            oValue = this.files[0]; //TODO if "input file multiple" need loop each value
        }
        oFormData.append(this.name, oValue);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/xhr',
    type: "POST",
    data: oFormData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    error: function (oRequest, sTextStatus, oErrorThrown){
        console.log(sTextStatus);
    },
    success: function (oData, sTextStatus, oRequest){
        console.log(oData);
    },
});
```